# put a loop in the __str__ class atribute

Tags: python, loops, class, for-loop, attributes

I wrote this simple class:

```
class MyDictionary:
def __init__(self):
    self.dictionary = {}
```

Then I fill my dictionnary:

```
>>> fruit = MyDictionary()
>>> fruit.dictionary["apples"] = 13
>>> fruit.dictionary["cherrys"] = 12
```

Then I would like that when I write >>> print(fruit), a dictionnary appears like:

```
I have 13 apples in my bag
I have 12 cherrys in my bag
```

So I create this simple attribute class:

```
def __str__(self):
    for key, value in self.dictionary.items():
        return "I have {} {} in my bag".format(value, key)
```

but this return only the first line:

```
I have 13 apples in my bag
```

and doesn't print the cherrys line! why? How can I put my loop in my **str** attribute?

thank you so much for helping me!

Answer (score 1):

`return` breaks the control flow of your functions and makes it *exit immediately* returning the value you passed to it, which is why it'll stop at the first iteration with the code you posted. That's exactly working as intended, see the documentation for the [`return` statement](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement).

You'll need to accumulate your partial results somewhere before returning them, e.g.:

```
def __str__(self):
    pieces = []
    for key, value in self.dictionary.items():
        pieces.append("I have {} {} in my bag".format(value, key))
    return "\n".join(pieces)
```